# Steps to run a bash script from Android app remotely

Tags: android, bash, redhat

I have a Redhat box with a few simple scripts on it. I'd like to run these scripts on that box remotely via an Android application.
Would I need to set up a webserver on the box and call these scripts over HTTP?

Comment: You would probably be better off opening a terminal on your droid and going over ssh. this of course pre-supposes that you have or know how to have a rooted droid.

Comment: connectbot on google play will let you ssh without root

Comment: @violet, @Drake: could you please elaborate how `terminal` or `connectbot` can be used **from Android app** ?

Comment: @lenik: [connectBot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) *is* an android app; it is a ssh client. there are lots of [tutorials](http://michaelchelen.net/articles/android-connectbot-ssh-key-auth-howto.html) on the i/web that explain how to use it.

Comment: @violet: please, pay attention: I have an app, it's my app, I wrote it. I want this app to run bash scripts on remote box. how can I achieve this using your approach with terminals and ssh clients?

Comment: OP never mentioned wanting to run the remote scripts programmatically ~but if so [it's still possible via ssh](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/are-there-any-command-line-ssh-clients-available-for-rooted-android-phones), from a script, from tasker, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Calling these scripts over HTTP would be your best option. Set up Apache + PHP, then make a PHP file with `passthru()` function, which calls a script and passes script output back to the Android app. Just make sure your scripts are safely stored on server and you don't try to send script content over HTTP -- that might be a big security hole.

Comment: -1. potentially dangerous advise imo,, OP says "I" not "my users"

Comment: tell you what ~i will un-1 this answer if you edit `Calling these scripts over HTTP would be your best option` to read `Calling these scripts over HTTP would be *an* option` :)